# nodejs read json and ignore the first occurrence of duplicate value

Tags: node.js, json

I have a json data like this.

```
[{
    "name": "Peter",
    "age": 30,
    "hair color": "brown"
}, {
    "name": "Steve",
    "age": 55,
    "hair color": "blonde"
}, {
    "name": "Steve",
    "age": 25,
    "hair color": "black"
}]
```

My code it does is, It will identify the duplicate and remove the second occurrence.

The code is :

```
var qdata = [{
    "name": "Peter",
    "age": 30,
    "hair color": "brown"
}, {
    "name": "Steve",
    "age": 55,
    "hair color": "blonde"
}, {
    "name": "Steve",
    "age": 25,
    "hair color": "black"
}]
 data = qdata.filter((obj, pos, arr) => {
            return arr.map(mapObj =>
                  mapObj.name).indexOf(obj.name) == pos;
            });
          console.log(data);
```

Output will be :

```
[
  { name: 'Peter', age: 30, 'hair color': 'brown' },
  { name: 'Steve', age: 55, 'hair color': 'blonde' }
]
```

Here it deletes the second occurrence and keeps the first one, But what I would like to get is remove the first occurrence and keep the second one

```
[
      { name: 'Peter', age: 30, 'hair color': 'brown' },
      { name: 'Steve', age: 25, 'hair color': 'black' }
    ]
```

How can I do that ? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply reverse the array and do what you want and reverse the result to match with your expected result.

```
qdata.reverse();

data = qdata.filter((obj, pos, arr) => {
  return arr.map(mapObj => mapObj.name).indexOf(obj.name) == pos;
});

console.log(data.reverse());
```

if you don't want to do that you can use the below code to get desired result.

```
data = [];

qdata.map((i) => {
  index = data.findIndex((u) => u.name === i.name);
  if (index >= 0) {
    data.splice(index, 1, i);
  } else {
    data.push(i);
  }
});

console.log(data);
```